# service get location every 20m or 3 second

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

i have an app that have a database and content provider. In one activity the user put the user id,longitude,latitude and timestamp 
I need now when phone is boot to collect the location and save it in the database every 20m or 3 second and when the airplane is on stop the service or when is off start the service.

here is the code:

Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    boolean isGPSEnable = false;
    boolean isNetworkenable = false;
    double latitude,longitude;
    long td;
    Location location;
    MyBinder myBinder = new MyBinder();


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplication().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkenable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnable && !isGPSEnable) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS IS DISABLE!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        try {
            if (isGPSEnable) {
                location = null;
                //checkPermission(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 0);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 20, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    Log.e("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                    Log.e("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    td=location.getTime();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "DT:"+td+"lat:"+latitude+"Long: "+longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
    Uri url = Uri.parse("content://gr.hua.android.contentproviderapp/COORDINATES");

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("_LONGITUDE",longitude );
    values.put("_LATITUDE", latitude);
    values.put("_DT", td);
    resolver.insert(url, values);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return myBinder;
}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
public class MyBinder extends Binder{
    public MyService getService(){
        return MyService.this;
    }

}
public Location loc(){
    return location;
}

}
```

in this service i get the location and put it in variables and after send it to db with the contentresolver

```
public class startReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

To start the service when phone boot

```
public class startReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(context,MyService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,3);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),3000,pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

To shechule the service every 3 second start

```
public class ScheduledStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    IntentFilter intentfilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    intentfilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    Log.d("AirplaneMode","Service state change"); // debugging
    boolean airplane_active = isAirplaneModeOn(context);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(context,MyService.class);
    if (!airplane_active) {
        context.startService(i);
    }else{
        context.stopService(i);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Airplane on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


    public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
        } else {
            return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and the receiver for airplane mode when is on stop the service and when is off start the service

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity" />

    <service
        android:name=".MyService">

    </service>
    <receiver android:name=".startReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".startReceiver1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".ScheduledStartReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

the problem is the service never start..

i dont know if that is a good logic to achive this i am a beginner in android yet so if you can explain with code or simple words..

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a different approach is to use a scheduler. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html. This will give you an idea of the options available. Choose according to your targeted API level. These will take care of airplane mode, data connection drop etc for you.

We have recently used Android-Job which was developed by the team at EverNote. https://github.com/evernote/android-job

The reason we chose this was down to the fact that it automatically chooses the right scheduling option for you. We could then apply the same logic across multiple android version easily.